# Most efficent way to get a list of strings with space delimiter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A project can have many tags. When editing a project I'd like to list all tags in a input field (stackoverflow style). In Rails 3 I have the following code, where I push all my names into an array before calling `join(' ')` but is there a quicker / more elegant way?

```
@tags = @project.tags

@tags_array = []
@tags.each do |tag|
  @tags_array << tag.name
end

@tags_string = @tags_array.join(' ')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe what you want is the `Enumerable#collect` method:

```
@tags_string = @project.tags.collect(&:name).join(' ')
```

Collect comes in handy when you're trying to transform one list into another list of equal  size, which is exactly the pattern here.

The `&:name` part means "call method name on the given object" and is something that could be spelled out as `{ |t| t.name }` equivalently.

The Enumerable library is really great and you should have a look through it and be familiar with the various methods as it can save you a ton of time.

Comment: Note that if you find `collect` confusing as this method name, it's also available as `map` (which I find clearer in addition to being less typing).

Comment: `map` is borrowed from Perl, as far as I know, and shows up in various other languages, and like `length` versus `size` it does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use threads while iterating through the @tags array. Have a look at this excellent article http://rubysource.com/threading-ruby/

Secondly it seems @tag is an array 
I would use map to return an array of names and then join them to a string

```
names = @tags.map{|tag| tag.name}.join(' ')
```

Comment: I don't think using threads to collect a list is a very good idea at all. You'd only need to go down this road if you were talking about millions of them, and even then the retrieval time would vastly eclipse the time required to extract the name.

Comment: I admit it might be an overkill but assuming a lot of array items and performing action(s)/processing on the array items.

Comment: You should know that grinding through an array of a hundred thousand items and calling a method takes near zero time. You should never thread unless you need it, as going down that road can create tons of trouble.